# Securing MYSQL tables from inappropriate access

Tags: c#, mysql, database, security

I have a consumer application (C#) and am so lost on security that I need suggestions even on what to google and start learning with regards to this problem. Basically I have a application that multiple users access a database. The database is structured in such a way that everyones data is in the same tables, and each has a identifier of "who this data belongs to" (example listed below). Our application of course has authentication so when you log in it says "you can only access your data".

My concern is that we have some rather shady competition who will no doubt try to pull our application apart if possible. If they can I am concerned they could change it from "only access this customers data" to "access all data". Is this a valid concern since all the authentication of "only access what data you are authorized to" is handled locally? If yes, is there a way to put the security at DB level with Mysql? I have tried various searches on Google, but without even knowing the correct terms I feel at a loss.

User    SaleID    SaleValue

Basically all our customers are plugged into this one table and all their data is stored together and pulled out of it based on their login etc.

Any help or even a search term to get me on the right track would be REALLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This article has some good tips: [Securing Databases](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps)

Also make sure that you are using C# PreparedStatements: [.NET PreparedStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the tables, unlock the table for authenticated users only and apply some more conditions also as you want.